# Targeting an Iframe using javascript with php inside with GET method

Tags: php, javascript, html, get, target

Im a complete newbie in being a php developer so please forgive me if im too dumb xD

Im have a link that will need to send a specific value for a variable using onclick, but the thing is, i used the get method for this but i cant bring the button to load it to the other iframe which is also inside the webpage.

heres the code of the first iframe with the link

```
   <?php 
<button name="link" type="button" class="search-button" id='.$propid.' onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Read More!</button>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                function reply_click(clicked_id)
                {
                     var javascriptVariable = clicked_id;
                    window.location.href = "propdetails.php?propid=" + javascriptVariable;


            }
            </script> ?>
```

and heres the other iframe with the name of "propdet"

```
<?php
    $propid=$_GET['propid']; 
echo '
    $propid<br>
<hr size="5">';
?>
```

Notes: "the two codes are in 2 different iframes on the same page."
Problem: "The first code loads on the same iframe where i clicked the link."
Goal: "I need to load on the iframe named ="propdet" without reloading the contents of the other iframe".

Comment: iframes are almost always a bad idea

Comment: You could suggest the code, i just need to make it work.. T.T

Comment: and i need to stop seeing people improperly use iframes.

Comment: my bad @dagon , could u suggest how could i make it work?

Comment: ` window.location.href = "propdetails.php?propid=" + javascriptVariable; ` i just want to make this target to an iframe

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<?php 
<button name="link" type="button" class="search-button" id="$propid" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Read More!</button>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function reply_click(clicked_id)
            {
                 var javascriptVariable = clicked_id;
                window.location.href = "propdetails.php?propid=" + javascriptVariable;


        }
        </script> ?>
```

and

```
<?php
$propid=$_GET['propid']; 
echo "
$propid<br>
<hr size=\"5\">";
?>
```

One thing to remember is that there is no interpolation of the variables with their values if they are enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: how can i target the " window.location.href = "propdetails.php?propid=" + javascriptVariable; " to the propdet iframe?